# Any way to program a system which automatically restores home / sql database

Tags: linux, shell

I have made two shell scripts

Script 1: It does all Home directory backups with name

```
 username_home_date.tar.gz
```

Script 2: It does SQL backups of all sites every 3 hrs.

```
username_databse_date.sql.gz
```

Now currently if I want to restore the site, I have to copy the tar file to

```
/home/username
```

and then untar there with all the permissions as well and then manually import the database.

Is there any way (for instance a program, system or script) that I can just select which backup I want to restore and do automatically?

Maybe like a cPanel addon thing.

Comment: Hey Mirage, hope you don't take offense to me editing your posts this evening. I'm just lookin' out for you. Trying to make things a little clearer, clean up spelling and punctuation and make it more likely that people will pay attention to your post.

Comment: sorry for that , i will take care in future. Actually i was in the hurry to post questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you write, which could be as simple as:

`zcat username_database_date.sql.gz | mysql`

Depending upon how you dumped the database(s), you might have to drop before sourcing the file.  Be careful.

Comment: IS it possible to to make a webpage for that so that it shows all backups in dropdown list and i click restore. But all restore is done at background by shell.Is this possible

Comment: It is technically possible, yes.  I cannot recommend a pre-existing solution for cpanel.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily be a capnel. If that possbile i can make a php page on main domain name and from there i can restrore backups. Can i use shell commands inside php language

Comment: You can make system calls from PHP using the system() function. Be aware though that a web page will be run as apache so may not and should not have permissions do do what you require. Alternatively you could get a PHP script to set a trigger such as add the job to a MySQL table, that a user with permissions to run the job can check from a cron script if there are any jobs in the table and process them. Just take you time and think about the security implications as you do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to let go of your script-based backup system, take a look at [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net). It can easily restore files. Databases have to be restored some other way though.